# "No file in /home/runner/work/... matched to [**/pom.xml]" error appears during the build process of Maven project

Tags: java, maven, github, automation, pom.xml

I created a test automation framework built on Maven and already pushed it to the 'develop' branch in my GitHub repo.
It was needed to build my project each time a PR created. So I created a build.yaml file and added it to my repo. But when I create a new PR - the build process fails because of this issue:

`Error: No file in /home/runner/work/report-portal/report-portal matched to [**/pom.xml], make sure you have checked out the target repository`

Here is my build.yaml file:

```
name: Build and Test

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master", "develop" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master", "develop" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
    - run: ls -la
    - name: Set up JDK 20
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '20'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: maven
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn clean test --file POM.xml
      working-directory: ${{github.workspace}}
```

I added this row `- run: ls -la` into the build.yaml and can see in logs that my POM.xml file is visible:
[GitHub logs 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m65vX.png)

Again, according to logs, my repo was checked out successfuly:
[Git Hub logs 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQVC1.png)

Any ideas why my POM file is not found?

Comment: Default for a pom file is `pom.xml` all lower case... change that in your git repo and follow standards... it's easier than adding supplemental configuration options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mvn clean test --file POM.xml`? In Maven, the `pom.xml` file is case-sensitive and should be named exactly as `pom.xml` and not `POM.xml`. In the `build.yaml` file you provided, you are referencing `POM.xml` instead of `pom.xml`, which is search by default.

You should modify this line to reference `pom.xml` in lowercase, like so:

```yaml
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn clean test --file pom.xml
      working-directory: ${{github.workspace}}
```

And renamed your file in your source code to `pom.xml`.

Comment: It helped me. Thank you! For some reason when I created a Maven project the pom file was created automatically with upper case letters.